# jquery colorbox and custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scrollbar, colorbox

I would like to use a [custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) with Colorbox

I am using Wordpress so Colorbox is loaded using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-colorbox/). All the custom scrollbar files have been loaded as per the instructions. I'm guessing that I need to apply to the `#cboxLoadedContent` div so I've loaded as per this code, however it's not working:

```
(function(jQuery){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery("#cboxLoadedContent").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Using Firebug there's no alteration to the standard coding i.e. the JavaScript isn't firing. However if I add to the div `#cboxContent` the JavaScript fires and a class `mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1` is added to the `#cboxContent` div. But this doesn't have a scrollbar so nothing is shown.

The question is why isn't it working on the right div i.e. `#cboxLoadedContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#cboxLoadedContent` is appended and removed dynamically each time a colorbox is opened or closed. **Both plugins need to alter the markup and add their own wrappers**, so simply calling mCustomScrollbar on either `#cboxContent` or `#cboxLoadedContent` won't work (mCustomScrollbar must wrap `#cboxLoadedContent` within `.mCSB_container` **after** `#cboxLoadedContent` is appended).

The best way is to call mCustomScrollbar function inside colorbox's onComplete callback. This way the scrollbar is added when colorbox has done its work which is append `#cboxLoadedContent` and load the actual content.

From colorbox examples:

```
$(".callbacks").colorbox({
    onComplete:function(){
        $("#cboxContent").mCustomScrollbar();
    }
});
```

Comment: works perfectly thanks! The only other thing I had to do was move this code right before the closing body tag

Comment: It seems this does only work for vertical scrollbars and not for horizontal ones using `axis:"x"` or `axis:"yx"` :-(

Comment: Doesn't seems to work for iframes. Anyone came across that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note about the code in the accepted answer. I couldn't get it to work with $("#cboxContent") as shown; I needed to use $('#cboxLoadedContent').

```
$(".callbacks").colorbox({
    onComplete:function(){
        $("#cboxLoadedContent").mCustomScrollbar();
    }
});
```